# Wicket - Save current layout / view

Tags: user-interface, layout, wicket, state, bookmarks

I have an application in which I would like the user to 'save the view'. I.e. I make heavy use of ajax to replace all kinds of `Panel` and use nested jQuery UI Layout plugin for 'frames'.

So basically, the view is defined as the (functional) tree of components, combined with the Javascript state of the jquery plugin, combined with the 'query' a user has given.

I'm wondering what would be a good strategy to save this view state, and how to load it again.

I though of keeping a sort of UIState-model on the page level, and pass it to all components. The components then use specific settings of this model to initialize themselves and changes in the components should be reflected back into this state model.

However, this gets complicated when a `Panel` is reused in several places. The reason is that a component needs, besides its knowing how to read its own state from the central modal, also take into account the location in the (functional) hierarchy of components.

What would be a good approach? Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: How deep are these Settings supposed to go? Do you expect that Panels embedded in Panels (etc) will still have the need to access the values saved in the Settings (and are used in other locations without those Settings?)

Comment: In theory infinitely deep. In practice more like three levels. Panels can and will be reused under different views

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on: "this gets complicated when a Panel is reused in several places," with more detail about how that complicates the general design you described? It will make it easier to give it some thought and maybe offer some suggestions -